# Socket.Connect with a IPv6 address throws a "Address Family Not supported" Error

Tags: c#, sockets, ipv6

I am trying to do a Socket.Connect() and when the IP address that i specify is in ipv6 format, the Socket.Connect() fails with the error message :

**[Address family not supported by protocol family](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668%28VS.85%29.aspx).**
An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used. All sockets are created with an associated address family (that is, AF_INET for Internet Protocols) and a generic protocol type (that is, SOCK_STREAM). This error is returned if an incorrect protocol is explicitly requested in the socket call, or if an address of the wrong family is used for a socket, for example, in sendto.

However if i uncomment the code in the below snippet, then the ipv4 address would be used to connect and now the call succeeds; Note that hostadd.AddressList[0] returns a ipv6 address.
Also note that i am connecting between Windows 7 64 bit machines which both have ipv4 and ipv6 enabled;

Why does connecting using an ipv6 address throw the error? The Socket.Connect() method [documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7ew360f.aspx) that :

> If IPv6 is enabled and the
>   Connect(String, Int32) method is
>   called to connect to a host that
>   resolves to both IPv6 and IPv4
>   addresses, the connection to the IPv6
>   address will be attempted first before
>   the IPv4 address. This may have the
>   effect of delaying the time to
>   establish the connection if the host
>   is not listening on the IPv6 address.is not listening on the IPv6 address.

```
                IPHostEntry hostadd = Dns.GetHostEntry(TimeServer);
                IPAddress ip4IP = hostadd.AddressList[0];
                //foreach (IPAddress ipAddress in hostadd.AddressList) {
                //    if (ipAddress.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork) {
                //        ip4IP = ipAddress;
                //        break;
                //    }
                //}
                IPEndPoint EPhost = new IPEndPoint(ip4IP, 123);

                Socket pSocket = new Socket(
                    AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
                pSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 2000;
                pSocket.SendTimeout = 2000;
                pSocket.Connect(EPhost);
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're specifying IPv4 in your Socket() call. Did you try using `InterNetworkV6` instead of `InterNetwork`? In my experience, (at least with C sockets) IPv6 sockets will support both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, but IPv4 sockets will support only IPv4.